# Button value doesn't change after first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've got this button which changes a boolean in the database after clicking it. If the boolean `PausedCMDBUpload = true` the button should display UNPAUSE if the boolean is `false`, it should display PAUSE.

The button is changing the value in the database like intended, however after clicking the button the first time the page will refresh but the text on the button stays the same. After clicking it another time the text will change.

Does anyone have a idea why the value on the button isn't changing after the first click? Any help would be appreciated!

**View**

```
<script>
    function ClickButton1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ClickButton1", "Devices")",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }
</script>

@if (@Model.ElementAt(0).PauseCMDBUpload == true)
    {
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="UNPAUSE" onclick="ClickButton1(); document.location.reload(true)" />
    } 
    else
    {
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="ClickButton1(); document.location.reload(true)" />
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void ClickButton1()
{
    var entity = db.Devices;

    foreach (var device in entity)
    {
        if (device.PauseCMDBUpload == false)
        {
            device.PauseCMDBUpload = true;
        }
        else
        {
            device.PauseCMDBUpload = false;
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why would it? You are posting to an action called `ChancePauseCMDBUpload` in a controller `Devices`. But the only action on the serverside you show is called `ClickButton1`. So I suppose somewhere in the process you get an 404 NotFound error

Comment: My bad, that's some old code I used for testing. I've edited my question.

Comment: Might be a timing issue. Your ajax call is async, thus you call `reload` before the ajax call is finished ...

Comment: Is it possible to try in the format...$("Button1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ClickButton1/Devices/"

Comment: Removing the async part didn't make any difference sadly.

Comment: `document.location.reload(true)` should likely be inside the `success`.

Comment: Also your C# doesn't need the `if`. Just use `device.PauseCMDBUpload = !device.PauseCMDBUpload;`.

Comment: Awesome, putting reload in success did the trick, thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code as follows:

```
<script>
    function ClickButton1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ClickButton1", "Devices")",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                var btnText = $('#Button1').val();
                if (btnText == "UNPAUSE")
                  $('#Button1').val('PAUSE');
                else
                 $('#Button1').val('UNPAUSE');
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }
</script>

@if (@Model.ElementAt(0).PauseCMDBUpload == true)
    {
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="UNPAUSE" onclick="ClickButton1();" />
    } 
    else
    {
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="ClickButton1();" />
    }
```